# SVN last commit number on cover : a minimal working example?

Tags: svn-multi

I read many posts containing the `svn`, `svninfo` or `svnmulti` packages, but I can not find a MWE on the web to get started with those.

For example, I use these following first instructions of the package documentation on CTAN

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\svnid{$Id$}
\begin{document}
rev: \svnrev ; date: \svndate ; author: \svnauthor
\end{document}
```

But, I receive only this output:

```
rev:-2 ; date: ; author:
```

My latex folder is under the sub-root of the SVN root like this:

```
my projet
  - Code (folder, root of svn)
  - .svn (folder)
  - Documentation (folder)
    -- Rapport(folder)
       --- main.tex
       ---- chapters (folder) 
            some tex files
    -- javadoc (folder)
```

Of, course I tried the `svn` under the root too. But with the same non-results.

I use this software: tortoiseSVN 1.8 under Win7 (miktex 2.9) and my latex editor is TexnicCenter2 (alls in 64 bits). The package are loaded on the fly.

Comment: You've got no SVN info following the `$Id$` string: what you see if not viewing a 'live' SVN directory. In your real case do you have the info there?

Comment: Thank you Ruben for syntax corrections in my text. I forgot to check my translation in Google translate, and from what I saw as corrections, it was not very clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to always go back to this excellent PracTeX article by  Martin Scharrer:  http://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-3/scharrer/

Answer (score 2):

Hum ! The very minimal working example that I give in my question above works fine in fact ! I read the documentation of Tortoise and i found there, by chance, the way to set the properties 'id', 'author', 'date', ... on the files (recursively). This option is not activated by default. Something to be know ;-)

Then i tried a new commit with a small change and ... miracle : The `$Id$` was replace by a

```
\svnid{$Id: lil-groupe1.tex 94 2013-12-08 21:47:02Z madit $}
```

And after 2 compilations, my tag `\myVersion.\svnrev` give me exactely what I wanted :-)

Then I found a solution to have the last number of the commit for any of all the sub-documents in this post:

```
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15579/svn-for-multiple-files
```

with adding `\svnid{$Id$}` on each page (at begin).

Great !

Sorry for answering my own question ... by chance. I'll still leave with the answer because it may help someone who - like me - might seek a solution for a long time. Luckily my project should not be delivered tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 0):

For those who - like me - use TortoiseSvn, have a look at this link

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-auto-props

With a little configuration, it is possible to automatically insert SVN properties in new TEX documents:

in the config file (access by `context menu > general > "edit" subversion config file`)

uncomment `enable-auto-props = yes`

add the line `*.tex = svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev;` below